# Using DataFrame to make highlighted regions of plot using axvspan

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

highlight_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('XY'))
highlight_data.columns = ['Start','Stop']
highlight_data['Start'] = [20, 25, 42, 56]
highlight_data['Stop'] = [80, 35, 48, 72]
```

And I am trying to make multiple highlights by doing:

```
plt.figure()
for i in highlight_data:
    plt.axvspan(i[0], i[1])
plt.show()
```

But, the plot I get isn't anything close to the expected result. I know similar questions have been posted, but I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Here's the result I get. But the result should be highlights from
20 to 80, 25 to 35, 42 to 48, and 56 to 72.

[image: Result]

Comment: Please add the result and how it differs from the expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to iterate over the rows of the dataframe, not the column-names.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

highlight_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('XY'))
highlight_data.columns = ['Start','Stop']
highlight_data['Start'] = [20, 25, 42, 56]
highlight_data['Stop'] = [80, 35, 48, 72]

plt.figure()
for i, row in highlight_data.iterrows():
    plt.axvspan(row[0], row[1], edgecolor="black", facecolor=f"C{i}")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: if I may: follow up question, how does your `facecolor` parameter work here? is `C` a local variable defined by you or is it part of the global scope?

Comment: `"C0"` is the first color of the current color cycler, `"C1"`  the second and so on.